# Expect loses connection after telnet and does not send any subsequent "expect send" commands

Tags: session, tcl, telnet, expect

I have a telnet session automated.. my problem is a little confusing but ill try to explain with example....

example1:

```
spawn telnet 172.23.144.180 2068
after 2000
send "\r"

expect "loader>"
send "boot n7000-s2-kickstart.6.1.1.66.gbin n7000-s2-dk9.6.1.1.66.gbin\r"
### HERE I NEED TO WAIT FOR 3 MINUTES FOR MY EXPECT STRING ####
### SO IM SETTING TIME OUT ###
set timeout 180

### AFTER 3 MIN ### 
expect "Feature poap enabled/disabled"
send "yes\r"

expect "Do you want to enforce secure password standard (yes/no)"
send "yes\r"
```

What's happening, scenario 1: It waits forever not sending anything to the console (I see the "`Feature poap enabled/disabled`" log on the console).

What's happening, scenario 2: If I give "`after 180000`" i.e sleep for 3 minutes; instead of 
"`set timeout 180`" : No matter what, script sends "`yes`" ie the first "`expect send`"..

I want my script to send "yes" only when I it sees "`Feature poap enabled/disabled`"... Can anyone help me do this?

I researched more and found out that this is happening with only telnet process..not regular process ( i.e not telnet )

```
package require Expect
set timeout 180
expect "Feature poap enabled/disabled"
send "Yes\r"
```

works fine; after 180000 also works fine...

Help is appreciated..

Comment: What OS is this on? Windows or some form of Unix? It *really matters* because of some non-trivial interactions under the cover on Windows…

Comment: add this at the beginning of your script: `exp_internal 1` to see why it's not matching.

Comment: I asked because Telnet doesn't work with Expect on Windows (I can explain why, but it's horrible and really obscure!) The simplest workaround is to use `plink -telnet` (where `plink` is part of the PuTTY suite).

Comment: AFAIK Telnet on windows is not an ordinary CLI, it uses the [TUI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text-based_user_interface). Scripting a TUI is hard with expect (if not impossible).

Comment: Used exp_internal 1 and found out that no matter what the string for expect is...It searches for the given string for a few seconds...then prints "expect: timed out" and it  sends.i.e "yes" in my case...... So i used set timeout -1 it works fine..it will wait for the string forever.... This is somewhat wt I needed..thanks guys for pitching in..

Answer (score 0):

Used exp_internal 1 and found out that no matter what the string for expect is...It searches for the given string for a few seconds...then prints "expect: timed out" and it sends.i.e "yes" in my case...... So i used set timeout -1 it works fine..it will wait for the string forever.... This is somewhat wt I needed..thanks guys for pitching in.. –